# ScrollTop between 3 vertically aligned divs won't work from MID to BOT and glitches from BOT to MID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**UPDATE:** *I have tried removing the viewport size for some of the elements, and removing some of the features, but I am still experiencing the same behavior described in the 5 steps, therefor still looking for any advice.*
[Latest fiddle iteration](http://jsfiddle.net/5ntopa3w/11/)

I have no clue why this is happening. I have 3 divs on top of each other and a fixed navigation. I'm using `scrollTop: $("#`targetDIV`").offset().top - 100` to get to the each of the three divs. The `scrollTop` is called from one of three `.click()` functions; one per button.

You should be able to simulate the issue Im describing in the title by following these steps:

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ntopa3w/8/)

1. Click on "Mid DIV" button and you're taken to the middle div with "Content of mid div"
2. Now click on "Last DIV" button and nothing should happen
3. REFRESH THE PAGE
4. Click on "Last DIV" button and you will be taken to the last div with "Last div content"
5. Now click on "Mid DIV" button and instead of to the middle div it goes straight to the top div with "this is the top level"

From the top div I can get to MID and BOT completely fine.

I'd greatly appreciate if you could tell me what am I missing,
or what could be possibly causing this weird behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `info_overlay` is scrolled, the `offset().top` of its children changes.

An alternative method is to save the `offset().top` of all its children before it is scrolled, then use the saved values for animating.

Also, since the children's IDs are related to the "btn" classnames, you can write one click handler instead of three:

```
$('.inf_con_block').each(function() {
  $(this).data('offset', $(this).offset().top - 100);
});

$('.inav_btn').click(function() {
  var d = '#con_'+$(this).attr('class').split('btn_')[1];
  $('#info_overlay').animate({
    scrollTop: $(d).data('offset')
  }, 1000);
});
```

**[Working Fiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/4pkemjhv/)**

---

**Update**

This can actually be done more simply.  Just add the `scrollTop` of `info_overlay`, and that will "offset" the `offset().top` of its children:

```
$('.inav_btn').click(function() {
  var d = '#con_'+$(this).attr('class').split('btn_')[1];
  $('#info_overlay').animate({
    scrollTop: ($(d).offset().top - 100) + $('#info_overlay').scrollTop()
  }, 1000);
});
```

**[Working Fiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhpxcg3e/)**

Comment: thank you.i would not have figure that out mysef. thank you so very much!

Comment: You were actually very close to a solution.  I've posted an updated solution, which doesn't require saving the `offset().top` positions in advance.